# ssh / scp / sftp slow. Transfers seems to be capped at ~64kb/s

Tags: networking, ssh, scp

Machine details:
`mediacenter@mediacenter-Aspire-R1600:~$ uname -a
Linux mediacenter-Aspire-R1600 3.19.0-51-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 21:22:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mediacenter@mediacenter-Aspire-R1600:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid`

From the ssh login it appears the openssh version is 
OpenSSH_6.7p1.

I have been able to transfer files at ~2MB/s to/from this system but now am getting 64-66kb/s max. I did recently upgrade from a ubuntu ??12?? to 15.04 and I believe this is the first time trying to scp from the machine and therefore just discovered the issue.

I can login to the machine and scp a file from another computer at 2MB/s but again trying to scp files from this machine seems to be capped at 64kb/s.

The cpu doesn't show a high cpu usage or a high load and I can spawn several scp processes to get files from the machine and they all top out at ~64kb/s each.

If I attempt so ssh in I see, what appears to be, some encryption keys being decoded to the terminal.

```
ssh -p 514 -v mediacenter@192.168.1.104
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.104 [192.168.1.104] port 514.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nicky/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.8
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 20:e9:00:1a:69:c9:fc:e5:29:fa:b3:50:46:e0:0b:a5
debug1: checking without port identifier
key_read: uudecode [ encryption gobbledygook ]
Host '192.168.1.104' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nicky/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nicky/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nicky/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nicky/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mediacenter@192.168.1.104's password:
```

My sshd_config on the problem machine. AFAIK I only changed the port. I tried to change the ServerKeyBits to match that on other machines, but that didn't fix the issue.

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 514
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768 #1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Not sure what else I can provide.

The system itself is wired, but other pcs are wireless.

The system is an Acer Aspire Revo 1600 w 3GB Ram.

Comment: `sftp`, `scp` and `ssh` are related but different. How do you measure the speed?

Comment: Well for `scp` it is just the speed that is reported when transferring a file. I'm not really splitting hairs when the difference in expected vs obtained is so large.